# Teradata how can I use count(distinct)?

Tags: sql, count, teradata

I saw some questions similar but I still couldn't figure out.

There is many columns, but to short, I want to count distinct by g1 column.
I thought I could just use COUNT(DISTINCT)...?

Please help me for this problem.

Thank you so much in advance

| G1 | C1 | expected results |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | 2 |
| 1 | A | 2 |
| 1 | B | 2 |
| 2 | A | 3 |
| 2 | B | 3 |
| 2 | A | 3 |
| 2 | C | 3 |
| 3 | A | 1 |
| 3 | A | 1 |
| 3 | A | 1 |
| 3 | A | 1 |

Answer (score 1):

Most (all?) databases do not support using `COUNT(DISTINCT ...)` as an analytic function.  So in this case, I would suggest just joining to a subquery which finds the distinct counts:

```sql
SELECT t1.G1, t1.C1, t2.cnt
FROM yourTable t1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT G1, COUNT(DISTINCT C1) AS cnt
    FROM yourTable
    GROUP BY G1
) t2
    ON t2.G1 = t1.G1
ORDER BY
    t1.G1, t1.C1;
```

Comment: It said G1 is ambiguous...?

Comment: @HS1204 Sorry...was missing a `t1` alias there.  Try it again and it should work now.

Comment: Still same... maybe other g1 as well...?

Comment: Sorry again, fixed the `ORDER BY` clause.

Comment: Yes!!!!! Millions thanks. I wouldn’t give up as data analyst because of people like you. I have been struggling for one weeks for that. It mean world to me. I would even buy you dinner if you are around hahaha  Thank you so much!!!!!!

Comment: I already did it. You are freaking badass!!! Today is the best day at work

Comment: Hey one more question. Do you think I can add that to after select? Like select and whole your query and from table?

Comment: @HS1204 Well maybe.  Perhaps a union query would do what you want.  You might want to open a new question.

Answer (score 1):

You can get a windowed count distinct, but you always need two functions, one possible way is:

```
SELECT G1, C1, max(dr) over (partition by G1) as cnt
FROM 
 (
    SELECT G1, C1,
       dense_rank()
       over (partition by G1
             order by C1) AS dr
    FROM yourTable
    
 ) as dt
```

Depending on your data and actual query this might perform better than Tim's query :-)

Of course, this can be modified for NULLable columns flagging the 1st occurance:

```
SELECT G1, C1, sum(flag) over (partition by G1) as cnt
FROM 
 (
    SELECT G1, C1,
       case
         when lag(C1)
              over (partition by G1
                    order by C1) = C1 
         then null
         else C1
       end as flag 
    FROM yourTable        
 ) as dt
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below query:

```
SELECT count(C1) from TableName  Group by G1
```

Answer (score 0):

If your database doesn't use `count(distinct)` as a window function, you can use the handy trick of the sum of `dense_rank()`:

```
select t.*,
       (-1 +
        dense_rank() over (partition by g1 order by c1 asc) +
        dense_rank() over (partition by g1 order by c1 desc)
       ) as expected
from t;
```

Given that `count(distinct)` as a window function is easily implemented this way, I am surprised that many databases do not support this functionality directly.

One nuance:  This counts `NULL` as a valid value.  You don't have `NULL` values in your sample data so I don't think this affects you.  But, if you wanted an exact equivalent:

```
select t.*,
       ( (case when count(*) over (partition by g1) = count(c1) over (partition by g1)
               then -1 else -2
          end) +
        dense_rank() over (partition by g1 order by c1 asc) +
        dense_rank() over (partition by g1 order by c1 desc)
       ) as expected
from t;
```